# How to Connect any Database in SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-connection

I'm Studying C# and in the Online Video Lesson its Used SQL Server in Visual Studio. But I have a lot of problems with Visual Studio in my Old PC and I did all the previous C# Lessons in SharpDevelop (Works great)...

I'm stucked in DataBase, cause its a basic topic about C# and Database (I'll study DataBase later) and I don't know how to connect SQL Server in SharpDevelop to continue the Lesson.

I already tried MySQL, but I don't know what products that I need to install and how to connect later (Some products of MySQL need Visual Studio :/)

So, I really wanna use SQL Server, but I dunno how use this in SharpDevelop, I tried some tutorials that didnt work... Pls I need this help

Comment: A SQL Server uses an MDF file for the database.  Old versions (2010 and older) of VS when trying to create a localDB (a mdf file) do not work properly.  If you are using the SQL Client library in c# you can create a connection string an connect to a database that is attached to a SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here isn't your choice of IDE. It's your code. I don't understand what you mean by "doesn't work", but if you're getting errors you should look at them when you're debugging as they'll tell you the issues you're having such as incorrect database name.

Linked is documentation on connecting to an SQL Server via `System.Data.SqlClient` using `SQLConnection` on Netfx 4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8

As the docs show. You connect to the database by

```cs
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString);
```

Where `connectionString` is your connection string to the database, IE: username, database name, etc. Linked is a site which tells you the Syntax for the connection string.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for Reply... 
I'm new in DataBase and its just a quick topic that I need to finish (I'll study more DB after) and in the Lesson in VS need to go in "Add Conection" and this dont work for me in SharpDevelop, that is now my problem

Comment: Sorry my difficulty to say my problem, my english is not good yet

Comment: I see. I googled around and looked at some other SO questions. There doesn't seem to be a way to do an equivalent of Add Connection in SharpDevelop. So you will need to create the database in [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) and connect to it (as stated in my answer) via code. Sorry that I cannot be of anymore help.